# Unable to proxy gRPC calls using Charles

Tags: grpc, charles-proxy

I'm unable to (SSL) proxy any gRPC calls from my Android app using Charles 4.6.2. The request always times out on `Received response header. Waiting for response body`. Interestingly, I can see both request and response content (body), but the client still fails with `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error code. I'm guessing that something fails on the side of Charles when confirming the received response, because `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` can happen even on a successful response. Disabling SSL proxying works for some reason though.

This is a sample log from the Charles debug console:

```
22:42:03    FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http.HttpProxyHandler                  Establishing HTTP/2 channel to CONNECT https://server.endpoint
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT settings 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER frame: SETTINGS 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER settings 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT frame: SETTINGS 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER settings 0 ack
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT frame: SETTINGS 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER window update for 0 268369921
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT frame: WINDOW_UPDATE 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT headers 3
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Parsed  #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT header 3 'POST https://server.endpoint/server.endpoint/MyRpcCall HTTP/2.0'
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT settings 0 ack
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.StreamHandler  #307075206 [server.endpoint] stream 3 starting
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER frame: SETTINGS 0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http.HttpProxyHandler                  Received request POST /server.endpoint/MyRpcCall HTTP/2.0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT data stream: 3 size: 107 END
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http.ProxyHttp                         Sending request POST /server.endpoint/MyRpcCall HTTP/2.0 to com.xk72.proxy.http2.v@9e9d902
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER frame: HEADERS 3
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER frame: DATA 3 size: 107 END
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER headers 3
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Parsed  #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER header 3 'HTTP/2.0 200'
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http.ProxyHttp                         Received response HTTP/2.0 200 for request POST /server.endpoint/MyRpcCall HTTP/2.0
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER data stream: 3 size: 229
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Receive #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER headers 3 END
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   Parsed  #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER header 3 '<empty>'
2021/11/11 22:42:03 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #307075206 [server.endpoint] CLIENT frame: HEADERS 3
2021/11/11 22:42:03 INFO     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   #307075206 [server.endpoint] SERVER frame handler runtime error
2021/11/11 22:42:03 java.lang.IllegalStateException
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.f.a(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.A.a(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.q.run(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at com.xk72.util.d.run(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
2021/11/11 22:42:03     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's also interesting is that the message content log contains 3 empty `next message` lines before printing the actual message. My guess is that it is due to the length prefix, but I'm not sure.

```
>--------------------------------next message--------------------------------<
>--------------------------------next message--------------------------------<
>--------------------------------next message--------------------------------<
>--------------------------------next message--------------------------------<
field: "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Mediator](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator) is a Cross-platform GUI gRPC debugging proxy like Charles but design for gRPC.

You can dump all gRPC requests without any configuration.

Mediator can render the binary message into a JSON tree, when you have the API schema, after Mediator v1.4.1 you can configure API schema by Server Reflection, proto Roots or file descriptors.

It support decode gRPC/TLS after 1.4.0 release, but you should download and install the Mediator Root Certificate to your device like Charles do.